# matplotlib - how to show entire scales in figure

Tags: matplotlib

Expected to see entire range of axis from -3 to 3 as the axes scales have been set to `(-3, 3)`.

Please advise how I can show from -3 to 3 in both X and Y axes.

```
cowers = np.array([
    [-3.0, -1.0],
    [-3.0, -2.0], 
    [-2.0, -2.0], 
    [-3.0, -3.0]
])
cowers
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.axis('equal')

ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(-3, 3, 7))
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-3, 3, 7))
ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax.scatter(x=cowers[:, 0], y=cowers[:, 1])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
ax.grid()
```

[image]

Apparently the scale is automatically adjusted.

```
angle = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

# For the same scaling
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html
ax.axis('equal')

ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(-3, 3, 7))
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-3, 3, 7))
ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)

ax.scatter(x=cowers[:, 0], y=cowers[:, 1])
ax.plot(2 * np.cos(angle), 2 * np.sin(angle))

ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
ax.grid()
```

[image]

Comment: Set the xlim/ylim _after_ you have plotted

Comment: @JodyKlymak, unfortunately no change...

Comment: Please see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html and note that `axis('equal')` will change your limits for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding figsize parameter to plt.subplots() made the entire axis range showing up. However still not sure why it is required.

```
# fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6)) 
ax.axis('equal')

ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(-3, 3, 7), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-3, 3, 7), minor=True)
ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')

ax.scatter(x=cow[:, 0], y=cow[:, 1])

ax.grid()
ax.legend()
```

[image]